# How to use super in python 3 Version

Tags: python, python-3.x

We can implement super() in python 3 like below

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, Name, Age):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Age = Age

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, Name, Age):
        super().__init__(Name, Age)
```

I have below case is it possible to implement super() for class ConnectInteractive

```
 class Connect(object):
    def __init__(self,ip, username, password):
         self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
         self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoaddPolicy())
         self.client.connect(ip,
         username=username,
         pasword=password)

class ConnectInteractive(Connect):
    def __init__(self,ip, username, password):
         self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
         self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoaddPolicy())
         self.client.connect(ip,
         username=username,
         pasword=password)
         self.client = self.client.invoke_shell()
```

since below code is repetitive:

```
  self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
  self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoaddPolicy())
  self.client.connect(ip,
  username=username,
  pasword=password)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `super()` from the `ConnectInteractive.__init__` method like this:

```
class ConnectInteractive(Connect):
    def __init__(self, ip, username, password):
         super().__init__(ip, username, password)
         self.client = self.client.invoke_shell()
```